# mysql standard way to detect error

Tags: mysql

Is there a standard way to detect errors when using mysql from cli in this way:

```
mysql --host=$db_host --user=$db_user --password=$db_password -v -v -v $database < file.sql
```

What I mean is I want to know what I can search for in the output. For example a warning message always has Warning. Does error always have Error in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on `sql_warnings`, `sql_note`, `log_warnings` (or `log_error_verbosity` after 5.7.2), and lots of things in `sql_mode`.  See [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html) for explanations.

Comment: My question is will an error always contain the word ERROR

Comment: No, there are a lot of "warnings" that you may consider to be errors.  And there may be "err".